# Wireless slow, but very odd

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a HP Pavilion dv6 laptop (win7), internet through the wireless timeouts. Even though it connects fine to the AP/router. The computer had a virus (searchnu?) and I backed up the usual and restored the laptop to factory image.

Problem is after the restore the internet through the wireless the same still... and connected via wired and everything worked fine. I was able to update the whole system. Internet worked perfect, speed great. But the wireless still was pitiful.

Ping tests with wireless are interesting:

```
Google= 18ms
Gmail= 18ms
Yahoo= 1023ms
8.8.8.8=30ms

Microsoft= Request Timed Out
Bing= Request Timed Out
msn= Request Timed Out
```

even though I get 18ms with google, the pages take a long time to load.
Is this a root kit? is it the wireless card in the laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to be the internal wireless adapter. 
Using an external usb wireless, wireless works fine.

I have never ran into a network card that would allow you to ping and ping would only work on certain sites.

btw, I did wipe the whole hd clean. And re-installed Win7 (bare metal).Which should have removed any root kit.

Answer (score 1):

Does wireless work for other devices?
Make sure you have the latest drivers for the wireless adapter.
Try resetting the wireless router

Comment: yes, I am using another HP laptop at the same time with the same wireless connection. Works fine. I used the built in HP advisor application to update everything. I should check the manufacturer for the wireless internal network adapter though...

Comment: tried a couple different drivers, the official latest from HP and the latest from the hardware manufacturer... no luck

Comment: I hate to suggest this, but windows is weird sometimes, and another (yeah i know..) reload could help.  The other possibility is the device is going bad.  If you can, load a clean win7 install vs the factory image and download the drivers from the other pc.  Hp puts so much garbage on there computers, its insane.