# Windows 7 VERY slow internet connection outside of safe mode?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection, internet-connection, safe-mode

I have a very annoying problem with Windows 7 and its network connection. 
In safe mode, i get a speed test of around 12 mbps. However, in normal mode, I get a speed of 0.06 mbps.

Naturally this is infuriating. I have uninstalled and ended all of the tasks i can think of, Spotify, Steam, AVG, Onedrive, and so on.

I am using this over a wireless network but all other devices are fine.

Anyone have any idea if it could be a service or system process that is causing the issue?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: I would scan your computer with free version of Malwarebytes Anti-Malware (http://www.malwarebytes.org)

Comment: Already tried all of the virus route and it doesnt seem to be the problem :/

Comment: In safe mode not all drivers alre loaded. Is it possible that you upgraded your WiFi drivers via something like Windows Update? That usually can cause problems. Download drivers from official site of your WiFi card and reinstall them.

Comment: @RJcreatives Did you try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: AutoRuns http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx but be careful what you disable, and just disable and not delete until you find the problem. Had a friend delete an entry they thought was slick, ended up being the app that allows you use you laptop pad :-)

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone, however none of them have made any difference :( at first I tested the speed and it said 5 mbps but then it got slower and slower and slower :(

Comment: One thing that many overlook is tools that do Wi-Fi scans, including Wi-Fi geolocation scans. Doing a scan requires the radio to spend a lot of time tuning into other channels instead of staying on the channel it needs to be on to get its networking work done. Do you have any tools/widgets that show you a list of nearby Wi-Fi networks? Do you have anything that might be constantly checking your machine's geolocation?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. I am the only 'techy' person in the house so if anyone was running that type of tool, it would be me. I am not sure if it helps at all but i am running McAfee internet protection, but that is still running in safe mode and causing no problem.

Comment: Also, in safe mode during a speed test, my network utilization reaches 10%, but in normal mode never reaches 1%. Not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wireless slow, but very odd](http://superuser.com/questions/490361/wireless-slow-but-very-odd)